# Text in the circle in Android

Tags: android, view

I wanna show a text in the circle, so I wrote this code:

```
public class ArcTextView extends View {
    private static final String QUOTE = "Cenral Line Is The Best Line";
    private Path circle;
    private Paint tPaint;

    public ArcTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ArcTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        circle = new Path();
        circle.addCircle(120, 120, 90, Path.Direction.CW);

        tPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        tPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        tPaint.setTextSize(40);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 0, 0, tPaint);
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

However, there are 2 issues:

1. I wanna start showing a text from the top of the circle and can't do it. I tried to change hOffset in drawTextOnPath, but without success.
2. Do you have an idea how to ellipsize a text when is too long?

Known problems: replace fixed values with DP.

Comment: for query 1: Transform/rotate circle by 90 degree using animation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to change start position of you text (from Top).

1. Rotate your circle by `90 degree` using animation.
2. Use **Arc** inplace of `Circle`. And set startAngle = +/- 90 degree.

   ```
   Path path = new Path();
   path.addArc(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, float startAngle, float sweepAngle) 
   // sample: addArc(0, 0, 50, 50, 90, 360);
   ```

Comment: I've just tried using Arc. However, setting startAngle (to 0, 30, -45) doesn't make any difference?